# Need to have 2 active release branches in git-flow

Tags: git-flow, release-management

We have a release branch which has already passed the testing stage and it's ready to be deployed in production.
But we are facing a big freeze period so we won't.
We also want to create a new release from develop branch with a new feature that can be tested in this freeze time.
the problem is: We use git-flow framework and we can't create another release until the current one is closed, plus some corrections are only in current release branch and not in develop.

What'd be the best thing to do in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just create a second release branch.   Before you can do that though, you need to solve your other concern:

> plus some corrections are only in current release branch and not in develop.

You can simply merge the existing `release` into `develop`. In fact, you can do that anytime you'd like. Some organizations even automatically merge `release` into `develop` after every new merge into `release`, just to make sure all the bug fixes are in `develop` as soon as possible.

Once you've merged `release` down to `develop` you can create a second `release` branch the same way you normally create one.